# Fractured Steerer Tube

Tags: steerer

This is a dispute between myself, and my Insurance (Yellow Jersey). I crashed my Canyon Aeroad CF SLX, when I clipped the rear wheel of the rider in front of me as a result I fell onto my right side with my bike. I had a fractured top tube as a result, which happen to have been caused by the right brake hood lever. According to report produce by my Insurance (YJ) mechanics this has been classified as incident related, but there's also a fracture on the steerer tube which they are claiming to have been caused by over tightening of the stem bolts. My bike has been inspected by Canyon and they have confirm that this is due to my crash. But Yellow Jersey are refusing to listen to Canyon, ignore all my reports that I have provided to them.

Please I need help, legal means of fighting YJ, any experience if any might have encounter similar situation on a Carbon bike or Insurance that refusing to settle.

They want to repair my frame and leave my bike with damage fork and have this return to me like that. I have took my case to Financial Ombudsman. This Insurance company are worthless and the people that works their are complete muron. I produce 10 pages of analytical facts, they still won't even read, let alone reason with me. Their mechanic are claiming the damage is not incident related, claiming to be as a result of over tightening of a bike that's less than a year old.

I have argue that no way bolts would have cracked the steerer tube when there's a plate in between them which on has a dent from the cracks that is coming from tube. Nothing is extruded out of the plate or damage or no screw indentation mark on either side of the plate..... Carbon Bike Repair at Leatherhead making me sick, plus the worst Insurance ever.

[image: stem]
[image: Plate and steerer tube]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles!  I'm not sure we can really help you in a dispute with your insurance company; I don't even know if this is actually a question.  (If it is, it's probably not on-topic.  Please read [help/on-topic].)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal dispute, a rant, and I am unsure what the question is.

Comment: Insurers do this.  They deny and reject and stall and try to avoid paying.  You have to do the leg work to prove it, and incur costs.  So absolutely document every cost you undertake for this whole exercise.  Keep every receipt.  Get the bike checked by an independent expert (at your cost and add that cost to the total bill.)  You'd think Canyon's input would be accepted, but obviously that's insufficient, or was not in writing.  You need to have documentation from an independent expert with unarguable qualifications to counter their shill expert.   1/2

Comment: Advice from randoms on the web is not sufficient - The members of this SE stack have experience but do not have the qualifications on paper.   
Basically show some spine to the insurer, that you know how they operate.  Only then *might* they take you seriously.   If not, you'll need to escalate and explore what legal actions you can undertake, which means getting a lawyer skilled in insurance.  Again, all at your cost with no guarantee that you'll win.    Good luck with your battle - it may take years to resolve.    2/2

Comment: Also, most governments regulate or oversee the insurance industry somewhat.  In the US, for example, most states have something like a "State Insurance Commission" where you can file complaints.  Wherever  you may be, you likely have access to something similar.